# Xtext cardinallities

Tags: hex, xtext

Is there also a way to express it for an absolute value like 6. I'm now executing it this way but this does not seem to be the way it should be. Thanks in advance.

```
terminal DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F');
terminal COLOR_HEX : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;  
terminal COLOR_HEX : DIGIT*6; <-- is there a way to achieve this?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (Xtext 2.19) no such syntax. The `Xtext.xtext` grammar says about `terminal` rules:

```
TerminalToken returns AbstractElement:
    TerminalTokenElement cardinality=('?'|'*'|'+')?
;

TerminalTokenElement returns AbstractElement:
    CharacterRange | TerminalRuleCall | ParenthesizedTerminalElement | AbstractNegatedToken | Wildcard | ^EOF
;
```

The same cardinalities are supported for non-terminal rules.

Therefore your current solution is fine.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment is appreciated. Perhaps you can answer my other question about xtext too! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957140/xtext-check-whether-string-is-url