# Xtext - Check whether string is URL

Tags: url, xtext

I'm completely new to Xtext so thanks in advance for your help.

I have the following:

```
terminal PATTERN_SRC : STRING '.png';
Pattern: name='pattern:' value=PATTERN_SRC;
```

I want the user to code it like this:

```
pattern: (URL to image ending with .png / .jpg / .gif)
```

Currently I'm checking it like this but this does not work.

Is there a nice way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sone remarks:

Don't use the feature `name`. This is a reserved keyword for calculating unique names of an element in a resource.

STRING is like this: "Sometext".
So what you want is `"somefile.png"`
What you described is `"somefile".png`
You could just use STRING and implement a validation rule to ensure your URL is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Greatly appreciated. Could you give me a hint on how to start on such a validation rule?

Comment: See here: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/103_domainmodelnextsteps.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer once again. I tried coming up with a solution to the problem but I did not come to that point yet. The problem is that I can't find a way to use Substring in the validation rules. Any ideas?